# More efficient way of writing PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

What would be the best way to write this block of PHP instead of listing each number??

```
  <?php     $name1      = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name1', TRUE);
            $name2      = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name2', TRUE);
            $name3      = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name3', TRUE);
            $name4      = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name4', TRUE);
            $name5      = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name5', TRUE);

            ?>
```

And here is the HTML that I will be using.
So I will want the list to display each of the 5 names.

```
            <li id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" ">
                  <?php echo $name1; ?> 
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like it:

```
<?php

  for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $nameN = "name{$i}";
    $$nameN = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ch_client_name{$i}", TRUE);
    // or $name[$i], if you can

    ?>
      <li id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <?php echo $$nameN; ?> 
      </li>
    <?php
  }
```

Comment: I used your solution thanks David. Had to change get_post_data to get_post_meta and worked perfect. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    ${'name'.$i} = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name'.$i, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array('ch_client_name1', 'ch_client_name2', 'ch_client_name3', 'ch_client_name4', 'ch_client_name5' )
foreach($names as $name) {
    $realname = get_post_meta(get_the_ID()), $name, TRUE);
    echo '<li id="'. theID() .'">'. $realname .'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$numberOfNames=5;
$names = array();
for($i=1; $i<=$numberOfNames; $i++)
    $names[] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ch_client_name'.$i, TRUE);
foreach($names as $k=>$name){
    echo "<li id=\"".($k+1)."\">\n$name\n</li>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might even want to consider using this, which gets all post meta *(custom)* fields at once:

```
$meta = get_post_custom( $post_id = get_the_ID() );
for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ )
  echo '<li id="client-'.$post_id.'-'.$i.'">'.$meta["ch_client_name{$i}"].'</li>';
```

Note I also fixed an error in the question when he asked for this:

```
<li id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" ">
```

The problems I fixed were:

- HTML @id attributes cannot start with a number *(so I prefixed with `"client-{$post_id}-"`)*, and
- `the_ID()` returns the post ID for each of the five (5) results instead of having a unique value that is required for @id attributes.